# Search and Replace in HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to use BeautfulSoup to search and replace `<\a>` with `<\a><br>`. I know how to open with `urllib2` and then parse to extract all the `<a>` tags. What I want to do is search and replace the closing tag with the closing tag plus the break. Any help, much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I would assume it would be something similar to:

```
soup.findAll('a').
```

In the documentation, there is a:

```
find(text="ahh").replaceWith('Hooray')
```

So I would assume it would be along the lines of:

```
soup.findAll(tag = '</a>').replaceWith(tag = '</a><br>')
```

But that doesn't work and the python help() doesn't give much

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will insert a `<br>` tag after the end of each `<a>...</a>` element:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag

# ....

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    a.parent.insert(a.parent.index(a)+1, Tag(soup, 'br'))
```

You can't use `soup.findAll(tag = '</a>')` because BeautifulSoup doesn't operate on the end tags separately - they are considered part of the same element.

---

If you wanted to put the `<a>` elements inside a `<p>` element as you ask in a comment, you can use this:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    p = Tag(soup, 'p') #create a P element
    a.replaceWith(p)   #Put it where the A element is
    p.insert(0, a)     #put the A element inside the P (between <p> and </p>)
```

Again, you don't create the `<p>` and `</p>` separately because they are part of the same thing.

Comment: Will that add it to every opening <a> tag as well?

Comment: See my edit - It will be added after the whole <a>...</a> element, so effectively, it will be only after the </a>.

Comment: Is BeautifulSoup.Tag valid? I am getting an error when trying this code.

Comment: It depends on how you import the module. I edited to show one way it can work - try it now.

Comment: FWIW it should be `a.parent.content.index`

Comment: @Lombo `a.parent.index` works as well, at least on BS 3.0.8. Older versions may not have that method.

Answer (score 5):

suppose you have an element which you know contains the "br" markup tags, one way to remove & replace the "br" tags with a different string is like this:

```
originalSoup = BeautifulSoup("your_html_file.html")
replaceString = ", " # replace each <br/> tag with ", "
# Ex. <p>Hello<br/>World</p> to <p>Hello, World</p>
cleanSoup = BeautifulSoup(str(originalSoup).replace("<br/>", replaceString))
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't replace an end-tag; in BeautifulSoup you are dealing with a document object model like in a browser, not a string full of HTML. So you couldn't ‘replace’ an end-tag without also replacing the start-tag.

What you want to do is insert a new `<br>` element immediately after the `<a>...</a>` element. To do so you'll need to find out the index of the `<a>` element inside its parent element, and insert the new element just after that index. eg.

```
soup= BeautifulSoup('<body>blah <a href="foo">blah</a> blah</body>')
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    br= Tag(soup, 'br')
    index= link.parent.contents.index(link)
    link.parent.insert(index+1, br)
# soup now serialises to '<body>blah <a href="foo">blah</a><br /> blah</body>'
```

Comment: Would I be able to add tags before with a -1. Say I wanted to do <p> and </p>. Could I but the <p> before using index -1 and </p> after using +1?

Comment: You'd add an element *before* the chosen element using just `index`, not plus or minus anything.