# How do I replace a HTML element with some new format in Python

Tags: python, html

What is a good way to replace an HTML tag like:

```
Old : <div id=pgbrk" ....../>....Page Break....</div>

New : <!--page break -->
```

`div` id might have many other values hence regex is not a good idea. I need some LXML kind of thing. Basically, my problem is to replace an HTML tag with a string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your `div` has a parent tag, you could do this:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.etree as ET

content='<root><div id="pgbrk" ......>....Page Break....</div></root>'
doc=LH.fromstring(content)
# print(LH.tostring(doc))    
for div in doc.xpath('//div[@id="pgbrk"]'):
    parent=div.getparent()
    parent.replace(div,ET.Comment("page break"))
print(LH.tostring(doc))
```

yields

```
<root><!--page break--></root>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain DOM http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

1) parse your source

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
datasource = open('c:\\temp\\mydata.xml')
doc= parse(datasource)
```

2) find your nodes to remove

```
for node in doc.getElementsByTagName('div'):
    for attr in node.attributes:
        if attr.name == 'id':
            ...
```

3) when found targeted nodes, replace them with new comment node

```
parent = node.parentNode
parent.replaceChild(doc.createComment("page break"), node)
```

docs: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html

Comment: XML seemed to be very strict on HTML content ?

Comment: yupp. I 'd use Beautiful Soup. I thought it'd be helpful to show OP the DOM as well. maybe it was just noise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073541/search-and-replace-in-html-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Yes this would have been fine except for the fact that the parseString ( not parse ) was not tolerant to my partially broken html . Thanks for the solution as it would be helpful in the case of an XML though .